# How to detect if a MediaStreamTrack has 'real' data after unpausing it?

Tags: video, getusermedia, mediastreamtrack

If you pause and then unpause a [MediaStreamTrack](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStreamTrack) using `.enabled = false` and then `.enabled = true`, there's a slight delay between the `.enabled` flag being true, and actually getting real data.

If you pass the stream to a video element, you'll see that you get a black screen at first, followed by the actual camera data shortly afterwards.

I'm wondering if there's a way to detect when the 'real' stream becomes available. I could periodically take a snapshot from the stream using a canvas, and check the data using something   like `.getImageData`, but that seems expensive.

Is there an event that is fired once data becomes available?

Note: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63152869/detect-if-mediastreamtrack-is-black-blank) looks similar, but is not. For remote connections, it suggests sending signalling events letting the other end know when the camera is paused/unpaused. I'm doing local processing, so I just want to know when I have useful data coming through.

Comment: Did you try using the track's `unmute` event? `track.onunmute= function(ev) {/* video now available */ }`   If that doesn't work in all the browsers you need, know this: disabled video tracks present all-black pixels (#000000 in color). That color almost never appears in real video track data. So you don't have to look at the whole `<video>` element to see if it's that kind of black. You can look at just one pixel. That takes a modest amount of  time and power per frame.